# Phrase for "suddenly wake up from a dream"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage

What is a natural thing to say when you suddenly wake up from a dream?

The impression I have in mind is of something like burst/tear apart or escape from the dream scene by waking up.

Comment: Do you mean wake up ***from*** a dream?  I don’t know what “wake up of a dream” could mean.

Comment: No you didn't, lol.

Comment: I think what you say depends on whether you were enjoying the dream and wanted to stay "in" or whether it was a nightmare from which you wanted to get out.

Comment: Good point Jim. How do you express in each case?

Comment: You wake up from being asleep, not from dreaming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *snapping out of* a dream, which has that sudden meaning.

You can also use [*startle*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/startle), as in *startled from a dream*, although this seems less sudden.

People are more often disturbed suddenly from daydreams than dreams, so you may find more uses by looking for daydream terms such as [*reverie*](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/reverie).

Answer (score 4):

You can say that the person **jolted awake**.

"In this context, it means to awaken suddenly (for example when waking suddenly from a dream). 
The sudden fear is the "jolt" that awakens you from your previous state."

Source of website: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/jolts-you-awake

Comment: Just realized how late this reply is lmao :'D

Comment: This is a good answer but could you include a quick dictionary definition of jolt to *show* that your answer's good? Also, you don't need to write an entire book :) all that you need is a little more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a verb that has been used to mean *wake up from dreams*. This means he woke up suddenly from a dream-sleep state, and this verb is

**start**

> to awake abruptly out of (also *from*, †*out*) sleep, a daze, etc.; to come awake with a start
>
> *Tarrant **started from his dreams** as a man seated himself in the next chair and boomed the words into his ear.*

(1922   H. Oyen,  *Tarrant of Tin Spout* vii. 60)

*Oxford English Dictionary*

† means obsolete (so today  one wouldn't say *to start out one's sleep*)

Comment: "Woke with a start" is the first thing that came to mind for me.